# What is the appropriate unit for phi coefficient

Tags: correlation, interpretation

I'm preparing some insights for non-technical, non-statistical background users.

Most of the stats are in terms of %, but my phi coefficient is (obviously) from -1 to 1 which users find confusing because they then assume, for example, a value of 0.75 means 0.75%

I could of course easily convert it to a number out of 100, which would probably be more intuitive to the users, but I feel would also be misleading because that might imply that the relationship is a %.

What's the best way to express this without being misleading or confusing?

Comment: If your users can handle a correlation coefficient (which goes from -1 to 1 and is unitless) why would this be more difficult?

Comment: My users have a general understanding of the concept of correlation, but don't come from a stats or math background, so the leap from seeing other values out of 100 and this value out of 1 is not an intuitive one for them.
It may well be that this question is more one of context and UX, but I thought I'd check here first for a more authoritative answer on how to communicate what a correlation is.

Comment: What did you do finally ?

Answer (score 0):

Why not rewriting your out-of-1 numbers into absolute out-of-100 numbers, and then replacing signs with "positively" or "negatively".
Which gives, non-confusingly,

```
-------------|----correlation---|
varA vs varB | 50% (positively) |
varA vs varC | 80% (negatively) |
```

Also, note that a percentage is dimensionless, it is simply another way of writing numbers. It is a notation, like the scientific notation. I mean, e.g. $0.05 = 5e-2 = 5\times 10^{-2} = 5\%$.

So you would not be wrong by implying that "the relationship is a %".

Comment: I suspect that many of my users will interpret it as 50% of people who have tagA also have tagB, and 80% of people who don't have tag A have tag C.
Wouldn't that be a misleading interpretation?

Comment: Long time no see ^^ What have you done finally @ChristopherJ ?